# structs c simple issue

Tags: c, struct

I'm in my first steps in c.

easy to start, but I just arrive to one point where I don't understand something... because I think I'm doing well.

its about structs, struct which have another struct inside, but when I make a variable I can't modify its parameters.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SND 1000000

struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct sending {
    char destiny[100];
    char address[100];
    char town[30];
    char id[9];
    struct date send_date;
};

struct sending_queue {
    struct sending elements[MAX_SND];
    int act;
};

main()
{   
   struct date one;   
   one.day = 34;
   one.month = 3;
   one.year = 1999;

   struct sending two;
   strcpy(two.id,"ABCD1234");

   printf("%s %i ", two.id, one.year);

   //struct sending_queue lotof;
   //lotof.act = 0;   
}
```

if I remove comments... I get an

> error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I know this is better if you do with *
but I need a simple example

why this error? and the solution?

Comment: You already declared `date` and `sending` as `struct` above. When you go to make a variable, do not declare it a `struct` again, simply say `date one;`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/dDfhz3)

Comment: There's no excuse to tag it c++ if it is C (or the other way around). Please refrain.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Guess it got optimized out there... as it should.

Comment: sorry about the tag, my fould
and thanks for the answer Cyber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a large object as a local variable. It is possible that your object simply does not fit into local memory (typically - stack). Your `struct sending` has more than `239` bytes in size. And the array of `MAX_SND` such structs inside `struct sending_queue` will occupy more than `239 * 1000000` bytes, which is about 227 MB. While 227 MB is not catastrophic by modern standards, this still might prove to be too much for a local object, depending on the stack size on your platform.

If you really need an object of that size allocated in advance (which is a big "if"), a better idea would be to allocate it dynamically, using `malloc`.

Comment: 252 for `sending` (assuming 4 byte `int` with maximum alignment (4) (a total of 3 padding byte))

Comment: i changed the MAX_SND to 100 and the program works fine
this was the problem? i cant access because is too big and maybe is not full in memory? thanks!